# Joining Pandas Series on a for loop returns null values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join, concatenation

I have a problem with a for loop, I have a function that returns pandas a series. What I am trying to do with it is append one of the columns I get from the function call doAnalitica into a empty series I declared above the for loop.

Here is my code:

```
for i in fiancial['symbol'][::100]:
    a = day.doAnalitica(i, '119', '3M')
    a.df['Close' + ' ' + i] = a.df['Close']
    df1 = pd.concat([df1, a.df['Close' + ' ' + i]], axis=1, join='outer')
```

When the script finishes it returns df1, however the data looks like this:

```
    0  Close GOOGL  Close AKAM  Close SLAB  Close CYOU  \
2018-02-20 09:30:00 NaN    1092.0000     66.5200     89.6500      26.930   
2018-02-20 09:31:00 NaN    1090.7200     66.3800     90.5000      27.050   
2018-02-20 09:32:00 NaN    1092.9900     66.6100         NaN         NaN   
2018-02-20 09:33:00 NaN    1093.1400     66.7400         NaN         NaN   
2018-02-20 09:34:00 NaN    1094.2800     66.8390         NaN      26.990   
2018-02-20 09:35:00 NaN    1095.5000     66.8350     91.6000         NaN
```

Besides Series[0], all the other series have values on the original call but when appended these disappear.
Does anyone know why that is?

Thank you for your help!

---

**UPDATED
The data is a Dataframe from which I only get 'Close' (Please see below).
Day is a wrapper for the api that gets the dataframe from the web (just pass ticker, frequency, and how long back to look for)

```
                     Open     High     Low   Close     Volume
2018-02-20 09:30:00  17.300  17.3000  17.300  17.300     701
2018-02-20 09:40:00  17.425  17.4250  17.425  17.425     100
2018-02-20 09:42:00  17.450  17.4500  17.450  17.450     100
2018-02-20 09:48:00  17.400  17.6000  17.400  17.550     644
2018-02-20 09:54:00  17.450  17.4500  17.450  17.450     150
2018-02-20 09:59:00  17.450  17.4500  17.450  17.450     300
```

Thank you again.

Comment: I think we need to see more of your code.  Where is `day` defined?

Comment: It would help to show the *before* data structure (to compare with this *after*) and then post your desired result.

Comment: Thanks guys, I updated my question as requested. To your point day is just a wrapper, financial['Symbol'] contain a series of stock tickers for which I loop once every 100 elements. (This was done for testing purposes)